# How to correct UndefinedVariableError in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When I implement code for one paricular value of state name (see Last_ residence in code)

```
andhrapradesh.query('Duration_of_residence=="All durations of residence" & Last_residence_R_or_U=="Urban" & Last_residence=="Jammu & Kashmir"',inplace=True)
print(andhrapradesh['Total_migrants'].sum())
```

It gives desired sum of outflow value for that state from pandas csv.
But when I tried to calculate for all possible names of state it's giving me error "UndefinedVariableError: name 'Jammu & Kashmir' is not defined"

```
states = ["Jammu & Kashmir","Punjab",'Himachal Pradesh']
for name in states:
    andhrapradesh.query(f'Duration_of_residence=="All durations of residence" & Last_residence_R_or_U=="Urban" & Last_residence=={name}',inplace=True)
    print(andhrapradesh['Total_migrants'].sum())
```

can you please figure out why it showing error and how can I do it for all values in list states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around `name` like you had in your manual code:

```py
df.query(f"... Last_residence == \"{name}\"")
```

so that it is seen as, e.g., `"Punjab"` as a string to check against but not bare `Punjab` which is sought specially, e.g., as a column name, hence the error.

(can use single quotes too...)

However, there's a better way: you can prefix a variable with `@` symbol, so you don't even need the f-string:

```py
df.query("... Last_residence == @name")
```